# Creating widgets: Getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: widget is not defined

Tags: javascript, widget

Hello I am trying to create a simple example for widgets.
My html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:widget="http://www.netvibes.com/ns/">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World Widget</title>
       <script src="js\widget.js"></script>
         <script>
        function widgetLoading() {
            if (widget) {  
                helloWorld();
            }
        }
        widgetLoading();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

My widget.js:

```
function helloWorld() {
         widget.body.innerHTML="Hello World!!!";
    
}
```

I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: widget is not defined
Do i have to add something more so that i can print "Hello World!!!"

Comment: Where exactly do you think a `widget` variable is being created?

Comment: @Taplar I have not much idea about that. just started to learn by google and would like to know how i can make it work